# How to get the index of an object(occuring multiple times) in a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, indexing, nsmutablearray

**Hello folks :)**

I have a quick question
 - For the following NSMutableArray:

*NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1", @"2",@"1",@"2",@"1"];*

**How can we get all the indexes for an object; supposedly I want to grab the index of 1?**
 So it should say 1 exists at index 0, 2 and 4.

Any kind of help is really appreciated :)
Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered just writing a loop??

Comment: Yea I did, but it would return only 1 index the last one. But I eventually got it.

Thanks though :) Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesMatchingObject:(id)anObject inArray:(NSArray *)anArray
{
    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [anArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [obj isEqual:anObject];
    }];

    return indexSet;
}
```

use it like

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1", @"2",@"1",@"2",@"1",nil];
NSIndexSet *matchesIndexSet = [self indexesMatchingObject:@"1" inArray:array];
NSLog(@"%@",matchesIndexSet);
```

returns

> [number of indexes: 3 (in 3 ranges), indexes: (0 2 4)]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this :

```
- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
```

That would give :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1", @"2",@"1",@"2",@"1", nil];

NSIndexSet * index = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){
    NSString* aString = obj;
    return [aString isEqualToString:@"1"];
}];
```

Best of all, you could create a NSArray category like this one :

## .m file

```
@implementation NSArray(Upgraded)

- (NSIndexSet*) indexesMatchingObject:(id)objectToSearch
{
    NSIndexSet *index = [self indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [obj isEqual:objectToSearch]);
    }];

    return index;
}

@end
```

That could be used like this :

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1", @"2",@"1",@"2",@"1", nil];
NSIndexSet* index = [array indexesMatchingObject:@"1"];
```

Comment: No I haven't. I am fairly new to iPhone programming. Could you give me an explanation how to use the method and call it. 

Thanks again!

Comment: Trying it but doesn't seem like its giving me anything. I have a couple of the syntax related issues in declaring NSPredicate. I am looking for it on google :)

Comment: @thebrowndoode : I check this and I come back.

Comment: @thebrowndoode : I've updated my answer. This one works fine.

Comment: It worked too, so thank you very much for the help and taking out time for it!